# How to set pivots on colorbar at customisable location in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, normalization, colorbar

I have some trouble in using Matplotlib colorbar, perhaps I am not understanding the documentation (I am not a native English speaker) or its core concept.

Suppose I have a matrix of data (shape, N*2). I want to make a scatter plot of this data and add a color scheme based on a column of label (N*1), in float. I know how to use colorbar and scalarmappable.

But, I am interested in some pivot values in this label column, and I wish to present these value in some interesting position of the colorbar. For example, label value 0, I want to position it at 1/3 place or in the middle -- which in the colorbar I choose could have a white or grey colour.

But if I understand it correctly, colorbar only takes data array that mapped in [0, 1] from the original data in [min, max]. In this case, the pivot value that I am interested would be end up in somewhere random, unless I define my normalisation function very carefully.

So to put the white colour I prefer for my pivot value is in the middle of the colour bar, I have to have defined the normalisation function which not only normalised my data, but also make the pivot value at the position of 0.5.

For my limited Matplotlib experience, this is the solution I know.

Ideally, suppose I have a column of float data, I could pick some pivot value, and give them some special position. and then I get them normalised and give to the colormap. The colorbar, however, I could set special colours for those special positions that I previous defined. and get a corresponding colorbar with the right tick locator and tick labels, that indicate my special pivot value.

I am looking for an easier way (from the standard lib) that I could use achieve this.

Comment: I am afraid of coding a special colourmap and carefully normalisation function. I want to have Stretchable colour map and multi-norm function. I wonder if anybody could understand me...

Comment: I would use a `LinearSegmentedColormap` http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap so you can put you pivot colors where ever you want.  I would suggest _trying_ something and then editing your question to include the code.  People will respond better to code than a wall of prose (and your English is pretty good).

Comment: ah ha, I just wonder if how long I could get responses here. yes I know linear segment colour map. This is the last thing I would do since there are already a set of colour bar available in matplotlib, but I just want to get it stretched so that I could position my pivot values there. I wish to use colorbrewer colormap. Thanks anyway. I will code `linearsegmap` right away.

Answer (score 1):

It will be very helpful if you can post a plot that you wish to make. But based on my understanding, you just want to do something to the colorbar at one or more particular spot. That is easy, the following cases shows a example of writing a text string at 0.5.

```
x1=np.random.random(1000)
x2=np.random.random(1000)
x3=np.random.random(1000)
plt.scatter(x1, x2, c=x3, marker='+')
cb=plt.colorbar()
color_norm=lambda x: (x-cb.vmin)/(cb.vmax-cb.vmin)
cb.ax.text(0.5, color_norm(0.5), 'Do something.\nRight here', color='r')
```

[image]

If you want to have value 0.5 at exactly 1/3 height of the colorbar, you need to adjust the colorbar limit using `cb.set_clim((cmin, cmax))` method. There will be infinite possible `(cmin, cmax)` fit your need so additional constrains are necessary, such as keeping the min constant or keeping the max constant or keeping the max-min constant.

Comment: yes, this is part of what I want, to do something at tick location from a positioning function. but now yet. How could we make a colour bar streched? like, RdYIGn, with yellow colour to the 1/3 place instead, and the whole colour map is streched to fit (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5357268). I think I might want to make a helper function to stretch those pre-defined colormap, perhaps from a [0, pivot1, pivot2, pivot3,..., 1] array. Thank you for the reply. :)

Comment: The main problem is,,, due to my language skill, I don't exactly know how to describe my problem. looking  my title again, man,,, this is exactly what you have answered.

Comment: Yellow color in `RdYiGn` is 0.5, you want to change it to 0.3333, while keeping your maximum value still in dark green? That's, stretch whatever above 0.5 and compress whatever below 0.5? I don't think you can do it efficiently without `LinearSegmentedColormap` @tcaswell suggested. Follow this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html